# CSS3 animation repeat transform effect

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create an animation effects which sort of "shakes" an image on hover. Its like the iPhone effects that appers when you hold down an App for some seconds and all Apps starts to shake.

It would be nicest if it was possible by using pure CSS3 but if its not possible I can use Javascript/jQuery also.

So what have do I got so far? Its just a one way rotation using pure CSS:

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27UeT/

About browser compatibility the only requirement is that it should work for Chrome.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.cssreset.com/2011/css-tutorials/css3-webkit-animation-shake-links/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to m90 link I came up with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/27UeT/1/

```
img:hover {

    -webkit-animation-name: thumb;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* The magic keyword for infinite*/
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes thumb {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `javascript`/`jQuery` solution, I created a little shaking [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27UeT/5/).

It uses `jQuery` custom animations to add a little shaking :) on hover.

It does however require the image to be `absolute` positioned.

**Update**
Unlimited shakin': [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27UeT/17/)

Comment: Wow it was a cool one and intensity, it didn't repeat itself. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SimonEdström Does it need to?

Comment: I serached for a way to repeat itself, have a look with my answer.

Comment: @SimonEdström I updated my fiddle as well, have a look. This will work in all browsers (normally). tested in FF.

Comment: @jb102000 Thanks but I have found what I serached for. However your animation dosn't stop when mouse is out. Thanks anyway